# Showing that orders are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

We say that $\mathcal{O}$ is an order if it is a commutative ring with identity, it is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module where $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z}\langle w_1, \ldots, w_n \rangle$, and the set $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}$. We want to then show that for all $x \in \mathcal{O}$, $x$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

My idea: In order to show that $x \in \mathcal{O}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, we need to find a finitely generated nonzero $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ such that $xM \subseteq M$. It seems like the obvious candidate is to select $\mathcal{O}$ as our module of choice. Then since $\mathcal{O}$ is a commutative ring, we have that $x\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$, which shows that $x$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. Applying this to all $x \in \mathcal{O}$ shows that our order is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this the right idea?

Comment: Yes. I would mention if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is not $\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ then $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a non-finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual argument is based on [this characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Equivalent_definitions):

> If $A \subseteq B$ are commutative rings, then $b \in B$ is integral over $A$ iff $A[b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module

An order $\cal O$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module.

If $b \in \cal O$, then $\mathbb Z[b]$ is a  $\mathbb Z$-submodule of $\cal O$ and so also finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Therefore, $b$ is integral over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I was trying to work within the confines of my class notes; we so far haven't used that as an equivalent definition. This helps though.